# Как прибавлять прогресс к кастомному Progress Bar

Tags: swift, xcode

Есть вью, откуда я получаю данные, которые выбрал юзер:

```
var volumeFromMilimetersVC = 0
var progressToMainVC: Float = 0.0

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int) {
    volumeFromMilimetersVC = volume.volumeArray[row]
    progressToMainVC = Float(volumeFromMilimetersVC)
}
```

Значения, которые может выбрать пользователь берутся из массива:

```
let volumeArray = [20, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 330, 350, 400, 450, 500, 600, 700, 800, 900, 1000, 1500, 2000]
```

Передаю полученную информацию обратно в другой вью в переменную `var progress: Float = 0.0`:

```
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    let vc = segue.destination as? MainViewController
    vc?.delegate = self
    vc?.progress = Float(volumeFromMilimetersVC)
}
```

В MainViewController создал: `@IBOutlet weak var progressBar: ProgressBarView!`
и написал функцию апдейта прогресса:

```
func updateProgress() {
    let volumeMax = Int(UserSettings.result)
    print(volumeMax!)
    let progress2 = CGFloat(volumeMax!) / CGFloat(progress)
    print(progress2)
    progressBar.shapeLayer.strokeEnd = progress2
}
```

Далее отдельным файлом нарисовал кастомный Progress Bar:

```
class ProgressBarView: UIView {

var bgPath: UIBezierPath!
var shapeLayer: CAShapeLayer!
var progressLayer: CAShapeLayer!
let main = MainViewController()
let milileters = MilimetersScreen()
let milileters2 = MililetersViewController()
    
    var progress: Float = 0 {
        willSet {
            let max = main.resultValue.text
            let volumeMax = Int(max ?? "0")
            let progress = CGFloat(main.progress) / CGFloat(volumeMax!)
            progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress
            //print(progress)
        }
    }
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath()
        self.simpleShape()
    }
    
    func simpleShape() {
        createCirclePath()
        shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = 15
        shapeLayer.fillColor = nil
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.lightGray.cgColor
        
        progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        progressLayer.path = bgPath.cgPath
        progressLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        progressLayer.lineWidth = 15
        progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0

        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    private func createCirclePath() {
        
        let x = self.frame.width/2
        let y = self.frame.height/2
        let center = CGPoint(x: x, y: y)
        print(x,y,center)
        bgPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: -CGFloat.pi / 2, endAngle: 1.5 * CGFloat.pi, clockwise: true)
        bgPath.close()
    }
```

Progress Bar почему-то не заполнятся.
Вопрос: как сделать так, чтобы progress bar заполнялся при добавлении пользователем различных значений и заполнялся до тех пор, пока не достигнет максимального значения, которое рассчитано для пользователя? Допустим, максимальное значение, рассчитанное для пользователя: 2500. Он добавляет из массива выше значения и они должны суммироваться и отображаться в линии progress bar'а.

UPD. Получилось сделать, чтобы прогресс бар обновлялся, однако после второго добавления он не прибавляется к предыдущему значению, а перезаписывается.

```
    var progress: Float = 0.0 {
    didSet {
        updateProgress2(with: progress)
    }
}

    @objc func updateProgress() {
    let userResult = Int(UserSettings.result) 
    print(userResult!)
    let progress2 = CGFloat(userResult!) / CGFloat(progress)
    print(progress2)
    progressBar.progressLayer.strokeEnd = progress2 / 100
}
view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(updateProgress)))

    public func addProgress(_ value: Float) {
    progress += value
}

     func updateProgress2(with value: Float) {
    let newProgress = value
    UserSettings.userProgress = newProgress
    defaults.set(newProgress, forKey: String(UserSettings.userProgress))
    progressBar.progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(progress / 100)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот минимальный пример такого функционала на основе вашего кода

```
vc?.updateProgress(with: Float(volumeFromMilimetersVC))
```

---

```
class MainViewController: UIViewController {
    
    @IBOutlet var progressBarView: ProgressBarView!
    
    private let maxProgress: Float = 2000
    
    private var progress: Float = 0
    

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
        progressBarView.maxProgress = maxProgress
    }
    
    func updateProgress(with value: Float) {
        progress += value
        progressBarView.updateProgress(with: progress)
    }

}
```

---

```
class ProgressBarView: UIView {
    
    let progressLineWidth: CGFloat = 15
    
    var maxProgress: Float!
    
    private var progressLayer = CAShapeLayer()
    

    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
        createProgressLayer()
    }
    
    required public init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        createProgressLayer()
    }
    
    private func createProgressLayer() {
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 1
        progressLayer.lineCap = CAShapeLayerLineCap.round
        progressLayer.lineWidth = progressLineWidth
        progressLayer.fillColor = nil
        progressLayer.strokeColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = 0
        progressLayer.frame = bounds
        
        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: progressLineWidth / 2, y: progressLineWidth / 2))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: bounds.width - progressLineWidth / 2, y: progressLineWidth / 2))
        progressLayer.path = path.cgPath
        
        layer.addSublayer(progressLayer)
    }
    
    func updateProgress(with value: Float) {
        if value > maxProgress {
            progressLayer.strokeEnd = 1.0
            return
        }
        
        progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value / maxProgress)
    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Но если принтить строку `progressLayer.strokeEnd = CGFloat(value / maxProgress)`, то там всегда результат 0.0, соответственно, progressLayer не добавляется

Comment: @Kenton а что приходит в updateProgress в MainViewController?

Comment: там приходит то значение, которое я выбираю, то есть всё нормально. В `class ProgressBarView` в функции updateProgress принтил value и maxProgress - тоже все нормально. Почему тогда получается 0.0 не понятно

Comment: @Kenton ну тогда если value и maxProgress оба не равны нулю, значит деление одного на другое тоже не должно быть равно нулю

Comment: Разобрался, спасибо огромное!